# Passing a variable to iteration variable after break statement

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

How can I make the iteration variable `i` take the value of the variable `lc` after breaking out of the loop? Thank you. Code below:

```
a = [155, 157, 83, 121, 112, 137, 129, 159]
b = [145, 148, 66, 117, 101, 131, 107, 153]

i = 0
high = a[0]
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] > high:
        high = a[i]
        for j in range(i, len(a)):
            if a[j] > high:
                lv = min(b[i:j])
                lc = b.index(lv, i, j)
                dd = (lv/high-1)*100
                print(high, lv, dd)
                high = a[lc]
                break
    i += 1
```

Comment: What's wrong with putting `i = lc` right before `break`?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. Thank you, by the way, for answering.

Comment: Also consider refactoring to use the more pythonic `for x in y` rather than using indexing.

Comment: @JacobFaib That won't work if he wants to change the way the iteration variable is incremented in the loop.

Comment: How can it not work? It's exactly what you asked for. Maybe that's not really what you want. Do you need this to replace `i += 1`?

Comment: @Barmar Presumably it only breaks out of the inner loop and it's overwritten in the outer loop.

Comment: Did you mean: `i = lc - 1`? That way the `i += 1` will mean `i` ends up correct.

Comment: @DinDin224 can you explain what this code is supposed to achieve? Likely there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Code is supposed to calculate the maximum drawdown of each maximum in list a by "reseting" the while loop at the minimum of list b each time a drawdown calculation is done